# Windows phone Indoor Augmented Reality

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, augmented-reality, indoor-positioning-system

I need to make an aplication for windows phone that uses augmented reality inside a building.
It's just for one building. 
Can anyone tell me if is that even possible, because is indoors and GPS wont work. 
I'm thinking on doing a Matrix were i put manualy all divisions and points of interest and so on (i will need to apply dijstrka or A* so the matrix is needed anyway). 
But how can i navigate and use AR with that matrix in windows phone? Is it possible?
If so can anyone provide some tutorial or sample? Or some clues to get me in the right direction.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: This will be pretty hard, I guess. You could use Bluetooth "markers" with well defined placements throughout the building to position the user in the room and readings of the placement sensors to give him an orientation.

Comment: Wireless markers will be unreliable.  They would be too close to do a "ping"-style distance calculation.  In order to do an accurate mapping of an internal space, you'd need to use the gyro capabilities in combination with visual markers.

Comment: With the sensors of the phone (gyro, compass, etc) i can navigate throught the building (matrix) at a decent precision. My only problem is knowing the starting point exactly without any external help (like QR codes, AP's..). That is not possible is it?

Comment: @DaveSwersky: Do you have experience with this kind of positioning? I don't, I am just thinking that wireless markers could be accurate enough because people on foot are not moving fast. I am thinking triangulation here. Won't that work?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth that dont work cause the IT guys in that building are always changing the AP's location.

Comment: @user1787010: Haha, well, that might be a problem ;-) But Dave sounded like it wouldn't even work when they are fixed and at well known locations. That's what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written quite a few AR apps for WP. There are one major problems with this: to do AR on such a small scale, points of interest within such a small area like a building requires very high accuracy for both location and orientation to be useful. As you say your GPS isn't really working inside and even if it did on that scale you need at least accuracy down to ~1 foot. Secondary you need pretty accurate angular precision, but again the motion sensor in the phone isn't that accurate even in an outside environment. It gets way worse inside a building because the metal in the construction can significantly offset the compass (I often see errors >90° inside).
so unless you find some external location and orientation sensor that can work at that accuracy inside, I would say its not possible to make anything that's really useful.

I do have an article how to at least do AR rendering on a windows phone at my blog http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/12/07/Building-an-Augmented-Reality-XAML-control.aspx but again I wouldn't expect that great a result in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your elucidative awnser. I will read your blog and try to figure something up.